# Problems installing ubuntu on windows machine

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

[image: This is the error I am getting when trying to boot from my usb mounted with ubuntu using the universal usb installer]

I am trying to install ubuntu 14.04.2 LTE. I have a lunovo ideapad with windows 8. I have followed all necessary steps flawlessly, and even factory reset my laptop to make this smoother. I get this error when trying to boot and install ubuntu. I also get it if i try to run ubuntu without installing. Also I tried re-downloading ubuntu, and remounting on my usb with the universal usb installer.

Is this error due to my computer, or the ubs/unbuntu? There was another option in the boot menu. It was check disk for error. I do not know if it was checking disk as in the iso disk or my hard drive, but a ubuntu lunch screen appeared and it was looking into some ubuntu files (on the usb), when it was done it said there was 2 errors. It did not say what kind or if it repaired it , or how to repair it. It only gave me the option to exit, then lunovo boot screen appeared and it stayed in a attempting to repair loop for quite a awhile so I gave up on that and shut down.

I would ask this in ask ubuntu, but I do not have enough "respect points" to upload an image.

Major respect to anyone who can help me out, I have been to get ubuntu for 2 days now, and I hit a dead end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message can appears in those cases:
1. Your hardware it not compatible, usually ACPI issue. Try to boot with additional options: "noapic" and/or "acpi=off". You should be able to set parameters in "Other options" [F6 key].
2. Your RAM is broken. Check it in "Test memory" option.

Comment: thanks for the help. It worked for ubuntu 15.04.1 for some reason so I am just going to stick with that.